# Pass custom arguments with redirect_uri

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to pass an API-key as an extra parameter to the redirect_uri when calling https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize but Azure AD won't let me do it.

Is there any way to send custom data to your url after the user has signed in with Microsoft?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is supported now. You can add query parameters to the redirect uri.

[image]

Auth request

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=cbc32712-ac2###32-802d-303998a6e712
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http://localhost/test?apikey=test
&response_mode=query
&scope=Directory.ReadWrite.All
&state=12345
```

The response

[image]

Reference:

[Redirect URIs can now contain query string parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-breaking-changes#redirect-uris-can-now-contain-query-string-parameters)

Comment: Okay, but how would I go about actually filling the APIKey with meaningful data?

Comment: @LoselMatos Is your APIKey static data or dynamic data?

Comment: It's dynamic, it depends on the user.

Comment: @LoselMatos If so, the query parameter along with redirect url is not apply here. You can use the build in `state` parameter. If a state parameter is included in the request, the same value should appear in the response.

Comment: Alright, I'll try that Tony, thanks for the help :)

Comment: @LoselMatos My pleasure.